# The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application SSDT in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(submitting on behalf of a client)

.........................

I am trying to connect snowflake DB from SSAS model (SSDT 32 bit) through ODBC driver (32 bit) but getting error while processing data

Error :The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application SSDT

So Followed the below link https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/how-to-set-up-a-linked-server-from-sql-server-to-snowflake

Followed the all steps as per above link and we are able to create linked server from SQL DB to snowflake and able to fetch data if we fire in SQL DB (`SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([*******},'Select * from "***"."****`) which working fine but when we try to process data from SSAS model i.e SSDT we are getting same error .

Is it not possible to create linked server with 32 bit ODBC DSN?

.........................

Any recommendations? THX!

Answer (score 0):

I would also setup 64-bit depending on your environment. The error is telling us there's a mismatch so why not make sure we are accounting for both.  It doesn't hurt to setup the 64-bit and then you have a DSN compatible for any future 64-bit applications.

Additionally, this blog may help as it has some good steps on initial setup:
https://www.decisivedata.net/blog/how-to-connect-azure-analysis-service-to-snowflake-or-other-cloud-odbc-database